# Default Google Map Using Geo in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using following code to locate location on default google map.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"?z=15");
 Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(in);
```

But using this code, when map will be open, there is no any point or mark or pin has been displayed on that location. It just looks like simple map only. How can i push pin on it? or how can i highlight that location on this default google map using this code?

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"?z=15"+","+(Label+Name)+");
```

this will open default map with given label name

Comment: Hie.. Thanks for your answer!!..But what i have to pass here with lable & name? can u describe me in detail?

Comment: you can pass any String Like New Delhi or name of Location

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"?z=15"+","+("New Delhi")+")");

Comment: I have tried above statement..it gives me toast like "Uable to load URL"

Comment: Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.detail_lat+","+Global.detail_long+"?q=New+Delhi");

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168522/starting-google-maps-app-with-provided-location-and-marker

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Uri.parse("maps.google.com/maps?q="; + STREET + "+" + NUMBER + "&" + CITY);

it will open the Google Maps App showing the Adress with Marker and "Bubble",
 hopw this work for you