# Open google maps app and show marker on it from my own apps activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to open google maps app from my own app activity.I want to show a marker on the specific location on the maps app.What I've found till now is this piece of code.

```
        String label = "shop";
        String uriBegin = "geo:" + lat + "," + lng;
        String query = lat + "," + lng + "(" + label + ")";
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

What it does is opens the map app but keeps showing me a `loading messagebox` saying `searching for:<lat>,<lng>(shop)` where `<lat> and <lng>` are my provided values . Whats wrong with this ?

I've copied this code from another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053352/android-how-to-launch-google-map-intent-in-android-app-with-certain-location).

Comment: hopefully your code is working well, there might be two reasons 1. Your lat/lon is somewhat wrong 2. Internet Connection problem. I was having the same isuue for some lat/lon.

Comment: yes you are right . I open the google maps app from the menu seperately and it is still not showing the map.Although my other apps are working fine . I am getting notifications and my google play app is running.That means internet connection is also fine. So only this map app is not working properly . Do you know the reason ?

Answer (score 8):

Update your google maps App.

Then (if isn't already working), you can try with this code:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f?z=17&q=%f,%f", latitude,longitude,latitude,longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```

Based on the question of:
[Starting Google Maps App with provided location and marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168522/starting-google-maps-app-with-provided-location-and-marker) to get that the marker appears adding the query tag to the URI