# Opening Google Map through Intent and adding marker in certain Latitude Longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

My app opens google map through ACTION.VIEW intent. When I give only latitude and longitude, the map displays the area without marker. To get the marker i used the following code,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+Double.parseDouble(dealer_lat)+","+Double.parseDouble(dealer_long)+"?q="+Uri.encode(dealer_nameX+", "+provider_location.toLowerCase()+","+provider_street.toLowerCase()));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

But this code does search of the location through the address i provide.
I need to add marker to the location given by latLng while also display the Marker label with certain text.
What should i do ?

Comment: You can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168522/starting-google-maps-app-with-provided-location-and-marker?rq=1) for the sake of completion.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + geoPoint.getLatitude() + "," + geoPoint.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" +
                trip.getPickupLocation().getLatitude() + "," + trip.getPickupLocation().getLongitude();

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));
```